# Sitecore using ADFS/SAML stays in SSL after login

Tags: ssl, https, sitecore, saml, adfs

How to make Sitecore use non-SSL  after an SSL ADFS proxy login?

We have a Sitecore site that uses ADFS (Active Directory Federated Services) to login to a common ADFS proxy and get a ADFS token.  This site is in SSL but when returned back to the calling page the page, it is remaining in SSL and when trying to access a non-ssl page we get an error message:

***Server Error in '/' Application.
Key not valid for use in specified state.***

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key not valid for use in specified state.*

note: we use this on other non-Sitecore sites and they do not return in SSL to calling page.

Comment: Do you have multiple servers behind a loadbalancer?  If so, are they sharing the same machine key?

Comment: Yes, we have multiple servers behind an F5 load balancer using the same machine keys.  I've even set up the <microsoft.identityModel>...<serviceCertificate><certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" with the same certificate and thumbprint.

Some additional info: after the site jumps to the proxy for login, and after a successful login, the page is directed back to the Sitecore site in SSL but links in the site are not all SSL. Maybe the SAML token is only available in SSL and when the non-SSL page tries to authenticate the token it can't get at it or decode it.  Thanks!